# How to call ng-template in for loop Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, popover, angular5, ngx-bootstrap

I open popovers click on anchor and popover data set in ng-templates.

I store 3 template in Array.

```
templates: array = [
    {'name' : 'template1'},
    {'name' : 'template2'},
    {'name' : 'template3'}
]
```

HTML code is here

```
<ng-template #template1>This is Template 1</ng-template>
<ng-template #template2>This is Template 2</ng-template>
<ng-template #template3>This is Template 3</ng-template>
```

NG FOR LOOP

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" *ngFor="let template of templates" [popover]="template.name" placement="bottom">
    {{template.name}}
</a>
```

Comment: What you want exactly?

Comment: You are missing a " at the end of your *ngfor

Comment: @RameshRajendran i want to open popover in loop using ng template

Comment: @GurpreetSingh Is this your actual code? you are defining a `template` array and looping over `templates` which is undefined https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xghsam?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: i edit my code.